# updating element in a list where list is the value of a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, matrix, nlp

I am trying to make a viterbi table with possibility of a specific word in a part of speech occurring inserted into a table where the rows represent all possible part of speeches and the rows are sequence of words in a sentence. I want to update the  cell with corresponding the likelihood (TP*EP) that a word of a specific part of speech can occur at in a sentence. But I'm stuck on inserting these likelihoods into the dictionary list.

I'm using the following for insertion, but it does not work. Is there an alternative to changing a specific element in a list where the lists are values of a dictionary?

```
likelihood = EP * TP
q[possible_pos][j] = likelihood
```

When I use this, I still get a table of zeroes when I am expecting some values in the table to be updated to floats(likelihood)

```
for i in range(2):  
    for j in range(len(word_list[i])):
        for pos in pos_list:
            q[pos] = [0 for x in range(len(word_list[i]))]
        try:
            word = word_list[i][j].split("\t")[0]
            pos = word_list[i][j].split("\t")[1]
            for possible_pos in word_dict[word].keys():
                try:
                    print(possible_pos)
                    if j == 0:
                        TP = Transition['Begin_Sent'][possible_pos]
                        EP = pos_dict[possible_pos][word]
                    elif word_list[i][j + 1] == ".\t.":
                        TP = Transition['End_Sent'][possible_pos]
                        EP = 1
                    else:
                        prev_pos = word_list[i][j - 1].split("\t")[1]
                        TP = Transition[prev_pos][possible_pos]
                        EP = pos_dict[possible_pos][word]
                    likelihood = EP * TP
                    q[possible_pos][j] = likelihood
                except KeyError:
                    pass
        except IndexError:
            pass
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(q, orient='index')
    print(df)
```

```
       0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
DT     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
NN     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
POS    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
MD     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
VB     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
VBN    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
IN     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
JJ     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
NNS    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
CC     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
RBS    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
NNP    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
VBZ    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
TO     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
CD     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
VBG    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
RB     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
VBD    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
PRP    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
PRP$   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
VBP    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
WRB    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
EX     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
RBR    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
WP     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
JJR    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
WDT    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
RP     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
PDT    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
UH     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
NNPS   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
JJS    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
SYM    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
FW     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
WP$    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
LS     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Add some more info to your question, what is not working? are you getting an exception? Can you provide expected output?

Comment: I am trying to update specific values in the table, which is generated using a dictionary where the values are lists. But when I update the values, I am still getting a table of zeroes.

Comment: Perhaps it's the conversion to a df from dict, have you checked the dict is the correct data?